# How to setup and call an AngularJS factory with ngResource and call it with parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Being relatively new to Angular, I would like some assistance in setting up a new factory that uses ngResource, rather than $http, and that I can pass parameters to.

Based on [this](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.ca/2013/08/ConsumingWebApiODataUsingResourceServiceOfAngularJS.html) example, I have setup a factory as follows:

```
app.factory('abstractFactory2', function ($resource) {
    //var odataUrl = "/odata/ContentType";

    return $resource("", {},
    {
        'getAll': { method: "GET", url: odataUrl, params: {options: "@options" } },
        'save': { method: "POST", url: odataUrl, params: { options: "@options" } },
        'update': { method: 'PUT', params: { key: "@key" }, url: odataUrl + "(:key)" },
        'query': { method: 'GET', params: { key: "@key" }, url: odataUrl + "(:key)" },
        'remove': { method: 'DELETE', params: { key: "@key" }, url: odataUrl + "(:key)" }
    });
});
```

I have been able to pass in the value of `odataUrl` from the controller, but experiencing some odd behavior.

In my controller, the call in my data setup is:

```
// TODO: pass in odata URL and odata options to factory

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read:
            function (options) {
                var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");  // Object {$inlinecount: "allpages", $format: "json", $top: 10}
                (new abstractFactory2.query({ options: odataParams })).$getAll()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        return options.success(data);
                    });
            }, . . .
```

I would like to be able to pass in the `odataUrl` (as well as other parameters), and the OData `options` from the function in my controller, and make subsequent appropriate `update`, `create` and `destroy` calls to the factory.

In Fiddler I see that there are two requests to the OData URL, one with partial parameters:

I tried passing in `odataUrl = '/odata/contentType' and reading it in the factory with`url: "@odataUrl"` but haven't been able to get that working.

```
GET /odata/ContentType
GET /odata/ContentType?options=%7B%7D
```

I would also like to be able to hook in to the `.success()` and `.error()` events of the call.

Answer (score 0):

might not the best way but can't you just say `url: odataUrl + params`